# Facebook requestWithGraphPath:andParams:andHttpMethod:andDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I managed to get logging in working with facebook and managed to get an active session.... However I am trying to post a photo to facebook or post a message to facebook. Can you tell me if I am doing it right? It doesnt seem to be working as I cant see anything getting posted on my wall.

```
 UIImage *image = combinedImage;
    NSString *strMessage = @"Check out my photo";
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setObject:strMessage forKey:@"message"];
    if (image) {
        [params setObject:image forKey:@"picture"];
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];
    } else {
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];
    }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think the key for the image parameter should be @"source" and not @"picture". Request call and path seem ok.

`[params setObject:image forKey:@"source"];`